# face_eyes detection and tracking using opencv

Tags: opencv

I am working on eye blinking using opencv 2.4.3 in C on Ubuntu platform.

I was able to detect a face and eyes in live video using Haar cascades, but when I tilt my face, the algorithm cannot detect the face, and I have also read on net that if the face is tilted it cannot be detected. So I think tracking can be helpful.

How should I track face and eyes in live video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the HaarCascade as **initial Detection** and then use [cv::GoodFeaturesToTrack()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#goodfeaturestotrack) to extract some **features**. Then for each **next frame**, you pass the initial features and frame (*from which you extracted th features*) and also the next frame to [cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=calcopticalflowpyrlk#calcopticalflowpyrlk) which will calculate the new posistion of these features. You can use cv::boundingRect(features) to get the cv::Rect that bounds the set of features.